# Alter Segment created

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm doing:

```
ALTER TABLE WG106_STAGE ALLOCATE EXTENT;
```

to change [Segment created yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nceKO.png) to `YES` from `NO`.

The value is changed, but after some time it's back to [Segment created no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6wGh.png)

It is not an fix operation?

I'm running on that table an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` and after that `TRUNCATE table WG106_STAGE drop all storage` every 10 minutes.

Comment: If you want to keep the segment, then why do you use `drop all storage`?

Comment: Why are you taking an interest in whether there is a segment created or not ?

Comment: OK, here is the full story.  I receive an error: **ORA-14300**: `partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions`. Regarding to (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_deferred_segment_creation.htm
) I decide to use `TRUNCATE table WG106_STAGE drop all storage` instead of `TRUNCATE table WG106_STAGE`.  It still did`t help me, so after comparing similar table (`WG143_STAGE`) I found this difference in Segment created parameter. Don't know if there is any connection between `drop all storage` and `Allocate extend`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that when the table is empty, than the parameter 'Segment created'  is automatically changed to NO.
As this was my first question it can be closed, because to say true, it wasn't established as needed.